# How can I asynchronously call a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, asynchronous

I'm trying to implement a WCF service as a Windows service. I'd like to call it asynchronously as there are some methods that may potentially run for a couple of seconds. Following misc. tutorials (e.g. from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx)) didn't really seem to do the job. I've got some bits working, but the data returned from the service to the client is not what I expect. Example code for the service on the server is as follows:

```
public interface ISomeService
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsnycResult BeginSomeMethod(string someString);

    Collection<string> EndSomeMethod(IAsnycResult asyncresult);
}

[...]

public SomeService : ISomeService
{
    public IAsyncResult BeginSomeMethod(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        // Do something...
        Collection collection = new Collection<string>{"Some Item", "Another Item"};
        return new CompletedAsyncResult<Collection<string>>(collection);
    }

    public Collection<string> EndSomeMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        CompletedAsyncResult<Collection<string>> result = 
            asyncResult as CompletedAsyncResult<Collection<string>>;
        if(result != null)
        {
            return result.Data;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I can successfully install the Windows service and also call it via the browser to see the WSDL. I can also add a reference to my "client" project to consume it - proxy classes etc. are generated without any errors. I can also call my methods like this:

```
[...]
    object async = new object();
    someService.BeginSomeMethod( "Some string", EndSomeMethod, async );        
[...]
```

The callback method looks like this:

```
[...]
public static void EndSomeMethod( IAsyncResult asyncResult )
    CompletedAsnycResult<Collection<string>> result = 
        asyncResult as CompletedAsnycResult<Collection<string>>;
[...]
```

Following this, result is null (i.e. the cast was not successful), and asyncResult does contain some properties and data, but not the expected (or wanted) string collection.

**Edit**
I can verify that the service method does what it is supposed to do (e.g. write to a log file, create a file or similar stuff).
**/Edit**

I've tried a couple of more approaches, but I'm somewhat confused as to what I'm doing wrong here. The examples available from Microsoft are apparently not correct (as read on some of the MSDN pages). I also found some other suggestions with event handlers etc., but was it the best way to go now?

Do I actually have to decorate service methods with the AsyncPattern = true in the OperationContract attribute? Or can I just use VS2010's facility to generate methods for asynchronously calling the methods?

I know that there are numerous questions regarding this issue, but after spending hours on this issue I feel quite stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `someService.EndSomeMethod(asyncResult)` in your callback to get the service result. This is actually part of the standard APM pattern. You'd have to do the same thing with say a `FileStream`.

> Following this, result is null

Yes, because `CompletedAsnycResult` only exists on the server. Your client can get any other type returned by the runtime. IAsyncResult is not part of the WCF wire-contract.

In practice, `asyncResult` will be an instance of some WCF-internal class.

Comment: Is there a page with a *working* tutorial with standard practices? There are too many pages with (imho) outdated code examples. It would be great to have an example with (server) service code and a client as a consumer. It seems there are callbacks on both sides, is this wrong?

Comment: First note that server and client are 100% separate. You can use sync or async on both sides independently (if you don't fully got this let me know). Indeed I have trouble finding a single code sample that I like. You might want to take a look at the FileStream.BeginRead sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxt5ahzw.aspx Async file IO works just like async webservice IO. Also this might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx (dig down into sub-topics).

Comment: Yes, that was one of the problems that I had - I can use the [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)] on the server, but I can also say (in VS2010) that I want it to "generate asynchronous operations" when creating / configuring the service reference. I will look at your links and see whether I'll get a simple example to work and get back with my findings.

Comment: Yes for invoking asynchronously from the client you need "generate asynchronous operations". What the server does is not important for the client because all that matters is the wire-protocol (SOAP over HTTP). The servers internals are abstracted away.

Comment: So what are the benefits of using each? When the client can handle requests to synchronous server methods asynchronously, why would I implement the respective operations on the server as asynchronous ones?

Comment: @Gorgsenegger if you expect the server to keep hundreds of simultaneous requests, basically. In other cases, don't do that. The same goes for the client: If you have less than 100 threads going you might not want to bother with async.

Answer (score 1):

Let me paste here the pattern I use here in WinForm .Net 4.0:

```
//Server WCF
public SomeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Collection<string> SomeMethod(string someString)
    {
        return new Collection<string>{"Some Item", "Another Item"};
    }
}


//Client
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var someService = new TypedServiceReference();
    someService.BeginSomeMethod("Hello", this.someMethodEnded, someService);
}
//will be called once the server reply
void someMethodEnded(IAsyncResult r)
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate//The callback is not in the GUI thread
    {
        var someService = (TypedServiceReference) r.AsyncState;//it is the last argument of the BeginSomeMethod() call
        Collection<string> result = someService.EndSomeMethod(r);//Will raise server or network exception (if any)
        this.Text = result.First();
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this?:

[wcf async processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959138/wcf-rest-not-processing-asynchronously?rq=1)

> It looks to me, from your example, like you're doing all the work
>   before the "Begin" call finishes; that's a common mistake I found
>   while learning the async pattern.
>
> Though I'm not familiar with its application in WCF, the Async model
>   more typically is a Begin method that launches some new thread with a
>   IAsyncResult object to be updated by that new thread. To "complete"
>   the action, when IsCompleted is set to true, the original caller is
>   expected to pass the original IAsyncResult object back to the
>   corresponding End method which returns the result. A trivial
>   implementation looks as follows:

Comment: Yes, I did, but I will again with a fresh mind, I may have been in a state of confusion...